# Compatibility Shimano rear derailleur RD-6300

Tags: road-bike, shimano, derailleur-rear, compatibility

I have this Shimano 600ax. Due to my stupidness I broke the body of the rear derailleur endings its life. There are other rear derailleurs (RD-6300) on ebay for example but these are very expensive going up to 100 pounds. I would like to ask some bike specialists if there are other derailleurs compatible with this one.

[image]

(This is not the original picture.)